# LInkedIn API: The remote server returned an error: (410)

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am facing issue while making call to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people
using C#. The following code was working fine before. Suddenly today I notice that it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
string fields = "id,first-name,last- name,site-public-profile-request,email-address"; //connections
string url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(" + fields + ")?format=json";
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");

WebRequests webReq = new WebRequests();
string response = webReq.GetRequest(url, headers);
profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LinkedInUserProfile>(response);
```

This is for my live site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
V1 is retired now so I need to move to v2 
Refrence Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context